# Padding between column and y axis line - is this possible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've searched everywhere in the highcharts api, and I am wondering if this is possible.

Please see the attached screenshot...

Is it possible to have the columns distanced from the edge of the chart boundaries like so? The y axis grid line should still take up the entire width of the chart.[image]

Edit: The distance BETWEEN the columns needs to be less than the distance between the columns and the edge of the chart. Imagine a box encapsulating the columns, i'm concerned with the padding between this 'box' and the edge of the chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put some empty columns on both ends and add empty strings to their categories [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xwkshbbr/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickWidth: 0,
            categories: ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', '']
        },


        series: [{
            data: [null, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, null]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes it, thank you. SteveP's answer did add the padding, but it added unnecessary xaxis labels that I did not want.

Comment: This works with x axis with type datetime, and category as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your chart is set up, you can use minPadding and maxPadding on the xAxis. e.g.

```
    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately this adds unnecessary x axis labels.

Comment: you should be able to correct that with a tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: I tried using this again with tickpositioner, and it also did not work for columns with categories for the x-axis. It only worked with x-axis with type 'datetime'